# Is it possible to have circulation without vorticity?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, fluid

Both circulation and vorticity have to do with rotation of a fluid element.How are vorticity and circulation are related.

Comment: In formal-ish settings, circulation is the spacial integral of vorticity. Vorticity is usually a point property, or a property of a very small region (such as a FEA cell).  We can derive the vorticity distribution function over a lifting surface (and wake surfaces) that will result in flow parallel to the surfaces at the surface, and integrating the resulting velocity vector perturbations over the domain yields circulation.

Comment: Also, be very careful how you use the word "rotation" in vector field contexts. Both the vortex sources and the resulting circulation are irrotational in the formal sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If no vorticity then, no circulation.

Mathematically, 
The flux of vorticity is circulation.

$ \Gamma = \int\int \omega~ ds$

So,  $\Gamma \rightarrow $ 0   when $\omega \rightarrow $ 0.

Physically, vorticity is just not a rotation of a fluid element. But it is the rotation of that element about its own axis (spin). (Please know about free/forced vortex for a kind of imagination).

So, circulation is non-zero only when there is a flux of vorticity.

Comment: It is very interesting and can further go on. 
The kutta-Jowkoski theorem relates lift with circulation ($L = \rho u \Gamma$) and Blasius theorem says momentum imparted on a body by the inviscid flow is zero. So, in nature, viscosity creates friction and hence vorticity $\rightarrow$ circulation and $\rightarrow$ lift!

Answer (score 0):

The **Biot-Savart Law** can be interpreted as the relationship between the velocity induced by a vortex tube and the strength of the vortex tube, i.e. its circulation.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law

Note: you need to be a little careful in ascribing causes and effects due to the unfortunate adjective "induced" in induced velocity. In classical fluid mechanics there is no action-at-a-distance, so vorticity cannot cause changes to fluid velocities at remote locations.